# Position section got disabled. Is this a bug in Developer Story View?

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I was adding details in my developer story for my current position in a company. I added details about my current position. Then I checked it and found that I have added it already in my developer resume. Hence, It was already there in the developer story. I removed the latest added position details and edited the previous one with some more details.
After that, It got disabled. Here is the image showing that.

[image: disbled position section]

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a bug due to a problem in our logic for deleting companies that have no users attached to it. I have unlocked the story item from your developer story so that you can properly edit or delete the item if you wish. A fix is incoming with the next production build. Thanks so much for reporting this!